# How to set a string value to django model Id?

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to web development. I want to manually define the identifiers of a model. So I add "id = models.AutoField (primary_key = True)" in my model class:

`mymodel class (models.Model):`

`id = models.AutoField (primary_key = True)`

When trying to set a string id I got the following error: The "id" field was expecting a number but got "Activity_0m91i8s".

Activity_0m91i8s is the string id

Is there a way to define the id string?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had to use :

```
id = models.CharField (max_length = xxx, primary_key = True)
```